# MySQL - Slow query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, prestashop

I have a problem optimizing a really slow prestashop SQL query *(mysql takes about 3.5 seconds to get the result)*.

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.*, a.id_order AS id_pdf, 
    CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 1), '. ', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`, 
    osl.`name` AS `osname`, 
    os.`color`, 
    IF((SELECT COUNT(so.id_order) FROM `ps_orders` so WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer) > 1, 0, 1) as new, 
    (SELECT COUNT(od.`id_order`) FROM `ps_order_detail` od WHERE od.`id_order` = a.`id_order` GROUP BY `id_order`) AS product_number 
FROM `ps_orders` a 
LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c 
    ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_history` oh 
    ON (oh.`id_order` = a.`id_order`) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state` os 
    ON (os.`id_order_state` = oh.`id_order_state`) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state_lang` osl 
    ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = 6) 
WHERE 1 
    AND oh.`id_order_history` = (SELECT MAX(`id_order_history`) FROM `ps_order_history` moh WHERE moh.`id_order` = a.`id_order` GROUP BY moh.`id_order`) 
ORDER BY `date_add` DESC
LIMIT 0,50
```

**EXPLAIN Result:**

[image: EXPLAIN Result]

What should I do ?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Do you have any indices?

Comment: Yes, there are created indices (default by prestashop)

Comment: what is the time of inner query, ELECT MAX(`id_order_history`) FROM `ps_order_history` moh WHERE moh.`id_order` = a.`id_order` GROUP BY moh.`id_order` and have you created proper indexes i.e. columns used for where compare?

Comment: Above query is fast (about 0.1005 second) I think indexes are correct.

Comment: Also try to run after removing IF((SELECT COUNT(so.id_order) FROM `ps_orders` so WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer) > 1, 0, 1) as new, 
    (SELECT COUNT(od.`id_order`) FROM `ps_order_detail` od WHERE od.`id_order` = a.`id_order` GROUP BY `id_order`) AS product_number , are these effecting the performance. another question i have about "ORDER BY `date_add` DESC", to which table this date_add belongs to.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff already found a problem with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` - thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

The `explain` looks reasonable.  Except.  The final `order by` is requiring a filesort on 204,480 rows, which is probably accounting for much of the time.  It is unclear where the column `date_add` is coming from.  But, perhaps you know that all rows will come from the last week or so.  If so, then an additional `where` clause might help:

```
where date_added >= now() - interval 7 day and . . .
```

Comment: When I removed `ORDER BY` clause it still takes about 3 seconds.

Comment: @user1768501 . . . What happens when you remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` ?  That also noticeably slows down queries.

Comment: Wow, now it takes about 0.0116 second, so I think you've found a reason of that slowness, thanks a lot, appreciate that.